# Replacing phone.apk with a customized app

Tags: android

I need to know what are the steps in modifying the phone.apk app on android, which allows to call and receive calls (and what is shown upon talking on the phone).

What do I need to do (of course I have a rooted device)? is it possible to do the tests on the emulator first?

my guess is that I first need to fetch get its source somehow, use some kind of system signing, do the changes and put it forcefully into the device, maybe also restarting it.

However, I've never done such a thing and I couldn't find much help in xda forums and here, maybe because it's pretty hardcore thing to do , plus it might not work well on some devices.

I've noticed that the only thing that shows this is possible is the calls-recorder patch, which is incredibly cool by itself.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you need source code. Phone app heavily depends on the radio interface layer and radio interface layer is proprietory to what kind of communications processor they use.

I believe you cannot test on emulator unless you are working on nexus family of devices. Also phone app runs on a particular shareduserid which can break other apps running with same shared user Id . So you will need platform certificate for signing which is next to impossible for release version of phone software.

One thing you could do is download cyanogenmod code for your phone , do changes , build and download the whole of software on the phone rather than just phone apk.

Comment: how do i do any of those solutions? i'm quite new to this and only done root operations as a power user , and not as a developer...

Comment: Then you will have to get comfortable with android source code, you could start by downloading Android source and build and change it atleast for emulator. Then you could look to do it on devices

Comment: suppose i find the code of the phone.apk , what then ? will it be enough to do my changes and build a new APK file ? won't i need any extra things ? also , where can i find the minimal files i need in order to compile this app ?